# Adding Child Element to XML using Linq-To-XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is how the XML is being created (using .Net 4.7):

```
    public XElement ConstructHvtPayload(PayPageRequest ppRequest)
    {
        XNamespace xNamespace = "http://www.litle.com/schema";

        var request = 
            new XElement(xNamespace + "litleRequest",
                new XAttribute("version", "9.13"),
                new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.litle.com/schema"),
                new XAttribute("id", OrderId), 
                new XAttribute("numBatchRequests", "1"),
                new XElement(xNamespace + "authentication",
                    new XElement(xNamespace + "user", "testuser"),
                    new XElement(xNamespace + "password", "winteriscoming")),
                new XElement(xNamespace + "batchRequest",
                    new XAttribute("id", OrderId), 
                    new XAttribute("numTokenRegistrations", "1"),
                    new XAttribute("merchantId", MerchantId),
                        new XElement(xNamespace + "registerTokenRequest" ,
                        new XAttribute("id", OrderId), right?
                        new XAttribute("reportGroup", MerchantId),
                        new XElement(xNamespace + "orderId", ppRequest.OrderId),
                        new XElement(xNamespace + "accountNumber", ppRequest.AccountNumber)
                    )));



        return request;

    }
```

What I want to do is add a If statement before the return to insert a new element "cardValidationNumber" if a particular condition is met.

I have tried the following (and other similar options):

```
request.Element("batchRequest").Element("tokenRequest").Add(new XElement(xNamespace + "cardValidationNum", "CCV"));
```

and I am getting Object instance not set errors.  I have also tried the following format:

request.Root......(But Root is not available as an option)

What am I missing? I suspect from the current replies it might be something to do with the custom namespace I am using??

Thanks.

Comment: XElement tokenRequest = doc.Descendants("tokenRequest").FirstOrDefault();  tokenRequest.Add(new XElement("ccv", new XElement("newElement","value")));

Comment: XElement tokenRequest = doc.Descendants("tokenRequest").FirstOrDefault(); comes back as null...This has been my issue

Comment: Are there any namespaces in the file.  Try XElement tokenRequest = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "tokenRequest").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom namespace.  That caused other issues when building it.

Comment: Without seeing the actual namespace I can' give a better answer.  You can get namespace from my results using : XNamespace ns = tokenRequest.GetDefaultNamespace();

Comment: Your query needs to use names in the correct namespaces. You need to provide a [mcve]. You've implied this example has had the namespaces removed, so your code does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edited to show a full and complete method.  This is exactly what I am using in my code...I am new to this so I figure I have FUBARed somewhere.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make much sense...where exactly do you want to add which node?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where "request" is coming from, it's hard to pinpoint why you are getting errors.
Assuming request is the XDocument itself, it should look like this

```
request.Element("littleRequest").Element("batchRequest").Element("tokenRequest").Add(new XElement("ccv", "NEW ELEMENT & VALUE HERE"));
```

Comment: Also, I don't know if it was a typo when you made the question, but there shouldn't be any spaces around "tokenRequest" in the original XML. That will give errors.

Comment: that was a typo - trying to sanitize the data - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this(using XPath not LINQ to XML though)

```
string path = @"D:\testing.xml";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            string item = "abcxyz"; 
            XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//tokenRequest");

            if (el != null)
            {
                XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("CCV"); 
                elem.InnerText = item;
                el.AppendChild(elem);
            }

            doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("<littleRequest><authentication><user>USER NAME HERE</user><password>PASSWORD HERE</password></authentication><batchRequest><tokenRequest><orderId>ORDER ID VALUE</orderId><accountNumber>accountNumberHERE</accountNumber></tokenRequest></batchRequest></littleRequest>");
var tokenRequest = doc.Descendants("tokenRequest").FirstOrDefault();
tokenRequest?.Add(new XElement("ccv", "NEW ELEMENT & VALUE HERE"));

string xml = doc.ToString();
```

It works for me.